How to load a Salesforce page with Cypress
I have a problem and I've tried to solve it, but I don't understand why it's not working. I run a test, and the test never finishes. I get "Your tests are loading....", but it doesn't select the button either. I'm attaching the information I have here:
describe('Salesforce Login', () => {
      it('should login to Salesforce', () => {
        // Visit the Salesforce login page
        console.log('Clicked on Login button');
        cy.visit('');
     
        // Fill in the username and password
        cy.get('#username').type('');
        cy.get('#password').type('');
     
        cy.get('#Login').click();

          cy.wait(10000);
      
          cy.get('button.slds-button[title="Show Navigation Menu"]').click();

          console.log('Clicked on element after login');

         
       
    })});

and the following:
index.js
import './commands';
require('cypress-xpath');

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // Check for the specific error message
  if (err.message.includes('Cannot read properties of undefined (reading \'addEventHandler\')')) {
    // Prevent Cypress from failing the test
    return false;
  }
  // Let other errors fail the test
  return true;
}); 

and the following:
cypress.config.js:
'''
const { defineConfig } = require('vite');
const react = require('@vitejs/plugin-react');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    // Enable experimental studio mode for Cypress
    experimentalStudio: true,
    // Specify the path to the Cypress support file
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.js',
  },
  // Set the viewport dimensions for the tests
  viewportHeight: 768,
  viewportWidth: 1366,
  component: {
    devServer: {
      // Specify the framework being used
      framework: "react",
      // Specify the bundler being used
      bundler: "vite",
      viteConfig: {
        // Add the React plugin for Vite
        plugins: [react()],
        server: {
          // Set the development server port
          port: 3000,
        },
        // Disable Chrome web security for tests (use with caution)
        chromeWebSecurity: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
'''


Many web sites, including Salesforce, use anti-robot techniques for login screens that Cypress cannot avoid.
But you you can work around it by opening a second window to perform the login.
Cypress.Commands.add('openWindow', (url, features) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', 'width=600, height=600')
    setTimeout(() => {
      cy.state('document', window.top.aut.document)
      cy.state('window', window.top.aut)
      resolve()
    }, 10000)
  })
})

cy.openWindow('https://login.salesforce.com?locale=eu').then(() => {
  cy.get('#username').type('admin')
  cy.get('#password').type('pword')
})

Since the domain is different for the new window, you must set "chromeWebSecurity": false in configuration.

